# How to prevent/suppress Decimal from using scientific notation?

Tags: python, decimal, scientific-notation

```
In [1]: from decimal import Decimal

In [2]: Decimal('0.00000100') * Decimal('0.95')
Out[2]: Decimal('9.500E-7')

In [3]: Decimal('9.500E-7').quantize(Decimal('0.00000000'))
Out[3]: Decimal('9.5E-7')
```

How to suppress scientific notation, and get `'0.00000095'`?

Comment: Please make your example copy-pastable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can format your output with the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

```
from decimal import Decimal
d = Decimal('9.5E-7')
print(d)
print(format(d, 'f'))
```

Output:

```
9.5E-7
0.00000095
```

But if you're planing to override `decimal.Decimal.__str__` or `decimal.Decimal.__repr__` you'll have a hard time, because they are read-only.